# How to solve $\ddot{y} = t^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am having trouble to solve $\ddot{y} = t^2$.

Step 1: Find the homogenous solution: (this part is simple)

$$y_H = c_1+c_2t$$

Step 2: Find the particular solution:  Since the nonhomogenous part is a polynomial of degree $2$, so $$y_P = At^2+Bt+C$$

Step 3:  $y = y_H+y_P$ and then plug in:

We have $$2A = t^2$$

which is not correct.

How should I modify this?  please advise, thanks!

Comment: You can just use straight integration here, nothing fancy necessary.

Comment: for particular solution try $At^4$ since your general solution has already terms in $t$ and constant.....you end with $A=\frac 1 {12}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y''=t^2$$
Integrate,
$$y'=\int t^2dt=\frac { t^3}{3}+K$$
Integrate again,
$$y=\int \frac { t^3}{3}+Kdt=\frac { t^4}{12}+K_1t+K_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $y_p=\frac {t^4}{12}+At+B$